# Spark dataframe after join null check for integer type columns

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am implemeting solutions for removing duplicate elements from two dataframes using left out join. After performing join condition, I have to check null columns for right table.

```
val llist = Seq(("bob", "2015-01-13", 4), ("alice", "2015-04-23",10))
val left = llist.toDF("name","date","duration")
val right = Seq(("alice", "2015-04-23",10),("bob", "2015-04-23", 23)).toDF("name","date","duration")


val df = left.join(right , left("name") === right("name") &&
  left("date") === right("date") &&
  left("duration").cast(StringType) === right("duration").cast(StringType)
  ,"left_outer").filter(right("duration").isNull)
```

But I am unable to filter out integer columns with null values. How can we do null check for integers after join ?

Comment: why do you cast `duration` (which is an Int) to String?

Comment: could you add input dataframes and expected output dataframes in the question.

Answer (score 1):

It's rather unclear what you want to achieve. The way you do it creates ambiguous column names. In addition, you reference the original (source) dataframe (`right`) in the filter condition, not the joined dataframe.

If you want to join them, you can do:

```
val df = left
      .join(right , Seq("name","date","duration"),"left_outer")
```

But will not result in any "null" columns because duplicated columns are removed.

```
+-----+----------+--------+
| name|      date|duration|
+-----+----------+--------+
|  bob|2015-01-13|       4|
|alice|2015-04-23|      10|
+-----+----------+--------+
```

Otherwise, you can try this:

```
val df = left.as('left)
  .join(right.as('right) ,
          $"left.name" === $"right.name"
      and $"left.date" === $"right.date"
      and $"left.duration" === $"right.duration"
    ,"left_outer"
  )
  .filter($"right.duration".isNull)
```

this will result in

```
+----+----------+--------+----+----+--------+
|name|      date|duration|name|date|duration|
+----+----------+--------+----+----+--------+
| bob|2015-01-13|       4|null|null|    null|
+----+----------+--------+----+----+--------+
```

EDIT:

If you just want to remove duplicates, you could to this:

```
val df = left.unionAll(right).distinct()
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. Actually I am trying to remove common rows in both dataframes by doing left-outer join and checking null data in right DF.

Comment: @Vinod look into the "except"  method of dataframes

Comment: @Vinod or use unionAll and then distinct, see my updated answer